# Access MacOS clipboard from C++?

Tags: macos, clipboarddata

It's pretty simple, I'm writing a C++ program, and I just want to be able to set or get the clipboard using some Mac API. I can find API references for objective C or using pbcopy/pbpaste on commandline, but how do I do this from C++? Am I supposed to jimmy it by just executing the pbcopy commands? If that is the correct way to do it, how do I differentiate between the clipboard containing text, containing an image, or containing a file directory or group of files?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, never-mind, Objective-C is an extension of C.

https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/d5c626fde1647f0b3e0d

I just have to learn how to mix the two. That's all.